# Is this a correct use of symbols in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, symbols, typeerror, incompatibletypeerror

I am working on a code challenge using symbols on line 4. 
What is the code on line 4 doing?
Is line 4 not using symbols correctly???

```
 1  class NameThingy
 2
 3    def format_name(name) 
 4        return "#{name[:last]}, #{name[:first]}"
 5    end
 6
 7    def display_name(name)
 8       puts format_name(name)
 9    end
10
11  end


my_name = NameThingy.new#("Jessica Flores")
my_name.format_name("Jessica Flores")
my_name.display_name("Jessica Flores")
```

## When I run this, I get this error message:

```
test.rb:6:in `[]': can't convert Symbol into Integer (TypeError)
from test.rb:6:in `format_name'
from test.rb:17:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Ruby has implicit returns, you can remove the `return` from line 4 and leave just the string interpolation

Answer (score 2):

This is because `name` is an `String` in your case any how, not a `Hash`. Look one example for the same :

```
name = "good"
name[:a]
# `[]': no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)
```

When you did method call like `my_name.format_name("Jessica Flores")`, ***name***, is then holding the reference to the `String` instance `"Jessica Flores"`. Now [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) expects only as its arguments either *numeric number* or *range* or *regexp* or *string*. But not **symbol** as per the documentation.

I would write your code as below :

```
class NameThingy

  def format_name(name)
    return name.split(" ").join(",")
  end

  def display_name(name)
    puts format_name(name)
  end

end

my_name = NameThingy.new
my_name.format_name("Jessica Flores")
my_name.display_name("Jessica Flores")
# >> Jessica,Flores
```

Comment: `String#[]` takes string as well. From documentation:  `a = "hello there";  a["lo"] ;               #=> "lo";
 a["bye"];               #=> nil;`

Comment: @DarekNędza Yes... I missed that. Do you use `vim` ? I need a help.

Comment: No, sorry. I'm only `pry`ing.